# Django Rest Frmework - Create API for User, Group and Permission

Tags: django-rest-framework

How do i create an API that contains `user, group and permissions.`

I want to combine `auth_user_group` and `auth_group_permissions`. how to import both models in my code. I cannot find the models in `django.contrib.auth.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such models: `auth_user_group` is the intermediary table for the M2M relationshipt between users and groups and `auth_group_permissions`the intermediary table between Permission and Group

if you wan't to display the user's groups and permissions on your API you'll need to use the serializer relations http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

hope this helps

Comment: Yes,,, It helps.. I just got it how to implement the relations.. Thank you so much..